# combine list item button navigate and swipe back

Tags: react-native, expo

**Updated: Replaced Code With Smaller Project**

I can't find a solution that works for what I am trying to do. Basically I have a list of objects with data, and each object has an arrow navigation button. This arrow button should populate the color screen and swipe right. While looking at the screen, the user should be able to swipe backwards to the last screen(Home). Below are some images to give a visual view of what I'm trying to do...

code repo: https://github.com/jamespagedev/react-native-expo-swiping/tree/unsolved

[image]

I've looked up several solutions, the closest I could find was one here: https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/implement-snapchat-like-swipe-navigation-declaratively-in-react-native-309e71229c89

However, the arrow solution covers the whole screen and not a list of items with navigation arrows instead.

I was thinking of using a `useEffect` to handle the selected color object data coming from the `route.params`, which would then invoke the screen swipe, but not sure how to implement this with both navigation(the back button) and the thumb held down for the color screen page.

Below is the code...

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import ScreenHome from '@app/screens/ScreenHome';
import ScreenColor from '@app/screens/ScreenColor';
import { frontendNavigations } from '@app/utils/HttpRequests';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={frontendNavigations.home.route as never}
        screenOptions={{
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#434343'},
          headerRightContainerStyle: { paddingRight: 10 },
          headerLeftContainerStyle: { paddingLeft: 10 },
          headerTitleStyle: { color: '#ffffff'},
          headerTintColor: '#ffffff',
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name={frontendNavigations.home.route as never} component={ScreenHome} options={{ title: frontendNavigations.home.screenTitle }} />
        <Stack.Screen name={frontendNavigations.color.route as never} component={ScreenColor} options={{ title: frontendNavigations.color.screenTitle }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

screens/ScreenHome.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, Pressable, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { MaterialIcons as Icon } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import data from '@app/data/Colors.json';
import { frontendNavigations } from '@app/utils/HttpRequests';

const Item = ({color, navigation}: any): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <View style={{...styles.itemContainer, backgroundColor: color.background}}>
      <Text style={{color: color.text, fontWeight: '700'}}>{color.title}</Text>
      <Pressable
        style={{margin: 0, padding: 0, backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(frontendNavigations.color.route as never, {color})}
      >
        <Icon
          style={{ alignSelf: 'center', padding: 20 }}
          name="keyboard-arrow-right"
          size={40}
          color="#67B5BD"
        />
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function ScreenHome(): JSX.Element {
  const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<any>>();
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.mainFont}>Select a Color</Text>
      <FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 20 }}
        style={{width: '100%'}}
        data={data}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Item color={item} navigation={navigation} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.title}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#000000'
  },
  itemContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    margin: 1,
    paddingLeft: 20
  },
  mainFont: {
    fontSize: 32,
    color: '#ffffff',
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    fontWeight: '700'
  }
});
```

screens/ScreenColor.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function ScreenColor({ route }: any): JSX.Element {
  const { color } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={{...styles.container, backgroundColor: color.background}}>
      <Text style={{color: color.text}}>{color.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

utils/HttpRequests.ts

```
export const frontendNavigations: {[key: string]: {route: string, screenTitle: string}} = {
  home: {route: 'home', screenTitle: 'Home'},
  color: {route: 'color', screenTitle: 'Color'},
}
```

data/Colors.json

```
[
  {
    "title": "Red",
    "text": "#ffffff",
    "background": "#ff0000"
  },
  {
    "title": "Green",
    "text": "#000000",
    "background": "#00ff00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Blue",
    "text": "#ffffff",
    "background": "#0000ff"
  },
  {
    "title": "Purple",
    "text": "#ffffff",
    "background": "#800080"
  },
  {
    "title": "Yellow",
    "text": "#000000",
    "background": "#ffff00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Cyan",
    "text": "#000000",
    "background": "#00ffff"
  },
  {
    "title": "Magenta",
    "text": "#000000",
    "background": "#ff00ff"
  },
  {
    "title": "Lime",
    "text": "#000000",
    "background": "#00ff00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Silver",
    "text": "#000000",
    "background": "#c0c0c0"
  },
  {
    "title": "Gray",
    "text": "#ffffff",
    "background": "#808080"
  },
  {
    "title": "Brown",
    "text": "#ffffff",
    "background": "#a52a2a"
  },
  {
    "title": "Dodger Blue",
    "text": "#000000",
    "background": "#1e90ff"
  },
  {
    "title": "Olive",
    "text": "#ffffff",
    "background": "#808000"
  },
  {
    "title": "Peru",
    "text": "#000000",
    "background": "#cd853f"
  }
]
```

I'm open to suggestions on this one. If it's too complicated to combine the header back arrow and thumb swipe, then at least just the home screen list arrows and the color screen thumb swipe back would work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack and Screen navigation has useful options and screen options for this sort of thing.

I made the following changes to App.tsx, and all is well:

```
export default function App() {
  const rightToLeftAnimation = { // <------------------ add this
    cardStyleInterpolator: ({ current, layouts }: any) => {
      return {
        cardStyle: {
          transform: [
            {
              translateX: current.progress.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 1],
                outputRange: [layouts.screen.width, 0],
              }),
            },
          ],
        },
      };
    },
  };
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={frontendNavigations.home.route as never}
        screenOptions={{
          headerTitleAlign: "center",
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#434343" },
          headerRightContainerStyle: { paddingRight: 10 },
          headerLeftContainerStyle: { paddingLeft: 10 },
          headerTitleStyle: { color: "#ffffff" },
          headerTintColor: "#ffffff",
          gestureResponseDistance: 20, // <------------- add this
          gestureEnabled: true, // <-------------------- add this
          gestureDirection: "horizontal", // <---------- add this
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name={frontendNavigations.home.route as never}
          component={ScreenHome}
          options={{ title: frontendNavigations.home.screenTitle }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name={frontendNavigations.color.route as never}
          component={ScreenColor}
          options={{
            title: frontendNavigations.color.screenTitle,
            ...rightToLeftAnimation, // <--------------- add this
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```